# News Mobile App How to build reading offline

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I have a problem with my news app. My news app have very articles, I am using UIWebview to load html to read those articles. I want to build the reading offline function for my news app. The offline data will contains html and images to display. I don't know the best way to build this function because My app need download the offline data fast. I am thinking my server will compress my data then send to the client. Then client extract the data from the compress file to get html and images. Please give me a solution.

Comment: Is this question for iOS or for android..?

Comment: I need a solution for both iOS and android

Comment: Make sure your saving the compressed data from server in Device and use them as Refrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a native plugin, through which you can download  files from server `asynchronously` in background.See this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html) which shows how to create plugin  using  `Phonegap`.I suggest take help of [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for  `iOS  plugin` ,which helps in asynchronous files download also its used by many apps.

Comment: Do you think i should zip the data? because i need download many article (html and many images)

Comment: Compressing would be a good option because you will eliminate the overhead of downloading multiple images.Also to handle failure scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Easily Solution:
Like kaar says. Write a native plugin to get html and images from u site and save it on mobile device.

But considering u need download data fast.I suggest u can write an service on server ,App download data from service. it will faster and save more data traffic.

BTW:Use socket(data stream) and web service (json,xml) using different data traffic.
socket less than json or other.